# Problem on Cinnamon keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon on Ubunutu 12.04 by terminal. Now all keyboard shortcuts work on Unity but do not work on Cinnamon. For example sound volume up is not active for Cinnamon. 
Despite to check Cinnamon settings these shortcuts haven't effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search cinnamon in [synaptic](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/synaptic) and unintsall all installed packages. Then installing cinnamon with requested packages would solve problems.